# How to show a topological space is metrizable given a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My question is rather general and I know there are similar questions but none of them seem to give a detailed answer. My question is suppose we have a topological space $(X,\mathcal{J})$ and we are given a metric $d$ and are asked to show it is metrizable what exactly do we do? I have read many times that to do so we need to show "the metric gives rise to the same topology" but that seems rather vague. But how does one actually do that, does it mean that we need to show that open spaces with respect to the metric are the very open spaces in the topology? An example explaining how this is done would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you have to do. Generally, you do this by showing that given a $\mathscr T$-neighorhood of any $x$, there is a $d$-ball about $x$ inside the neighborhood (thus every $\mathscr T$-open set is open under $d$), and then show that open $d$-balls are open in $\mathscr T$.

The best-known example is showing that the metric and order topologies on $\Bbb R$ are the same. Any open ball is actually an open interval, and any open interval contains a ball around each of its points.

Answer (score 3):

"does it mean that we need to show that open spaces with respect to the metric are the very open spaces in the topology" -> Yes, precisely.

You have to show that any open ball for your metric is an open subspace for your original topology, and that any open subspace for your original topology is a union of open balls for your metric.